# Using javascript and php in one document

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, cookies

I have table which display retrieved data from the SQL for one of the columns I am using the `onclick="sendVal(this.value)" function for radio button for which it send the value of the radio button .

I then perform some calculation and remove associated tags to insert the new tag.

My problem is I need the new value (after calculation) to be added to MYSQL.

My approach (weren't most efficient one) was to save it as cookie and retrieve in PHP on the same file, however it is sometimes requiring me to reload the page perhaps because its POSTING as soon as the page loads which is not unsetting the `COOKIES`.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function sendVal(item) {    

        yessize=Math.round(100*(voteyes/(voteno+voteyes))) + random;
        nosize=Math.round(100*(voteno/(voteno+voteyes))) + random;
        alert("Thank you for your contribution");

        document.cookie= totalyes + yessize+ ";";
        document.cookie= totalno + nosize +";";

       }
```

( *Where total yes or no is the name of the cookie e.g totalyes="name="; )

on the same document at the end I have the php code:

```
<?php 

    if(!is_null($_COOKIE['name']) && !is_null($_COOKIE['name2'])){      
        echo "in";
        echo $example= "INSERT INTO example-table(id,ip,value1,value2) VALUES (".$id.",".$ip.",".$_COOKIE['name'].",".$_COOKIE['name2'].")"; 
        $con->query($example);
        unset($_COOKIE['name']);
        unset($_COOKIE['name2']);

     }
   ?>
```

(i have tried if isset too)

Comment: In what order are these operations occurring?  Any PHP code on that page is going to execute before the page is displayed in the browser, and then never again until after the page is re-loaded.  It's not really clear from the question what the total scope of your operation is.

Comment: I would like to retrieve the cookie after it is been set

Comment: @hass.: Well, *are* you retrieving it after it has been set?  That's my question.  If all you want to do is send a value to the server one time, then why not just post the value in an AJAX request?  Writing to a cookie and waiting for the next page load seems awkward.

Comment: any ways I could retrieve the javascript variable in php in order add to mysql

Comment: Yes, several ways.  The simplest is probably to just create a PHP page which accepts an AJAX post with the value, stores it in your database, and returns JSON indicating success/failure along with any other response.  Then in your JavaScript code you'd perform that AJAX post.  Using cookies might also work, as long as you read the cookie *after* you set it, and it's not clear from the question if you're doing that or not.  Though, again, this approach with cookies seems over-complicated.

Comment: I would like to retrieve it after it is been set and it works if I use if(isset(cookie) however the cookie is never unset as reloading the page sets it again

Comment: If there's JavaScript code on the page to set the cookie, why does it surprise you that a cookie is being set when the page is loaded?  It's really not clear at all what the problem is or the full order of operations that your code is performing.  The code segments you've provided don't give any information about the context in which they run.  Either way, my advice still remains.  Just send the value to the server directly with AJAX.

Comment: sorry, I first add data from database into a table where for one column I have two radio buttons. Upon clicking the radio button the javascript function runs. The problem is I only want to retrieve the set cookie only once and after the javascript function has been performed with AJAX I would require a creating new file, if I could do it this way it be much quicker

Comment: Yes, you've effectively explained that.  But what you haven't explained (and maybe just don't have the requisite knowledge to even understand) is the order in which you're doing these things and specifically how it's failing.  You have code which writes a cookie, and you have code which reads a cookie.  That's a good start.  But if you execute them in the wrong order, it won't work. Or if you execute them multiple times, it'll have unexpected behavior.  You haven't defined any of that information in the question. If the code you show *does* write and read the cookie, then the code shown works.

Comment: I have the php code at the "END" of the file but it reads it as soon as the file loads, how do i only use the cookie as soon as it has been set in JAVASCRIPT and to use in PHP and then unset it. As upon reload it not  unsetting the cookies

Comment: PHP code executes server-side *before* the page displays.  So, yes, when you load the page *all* of the PHP code will execute.  You seem to be confusing server-side and client-side code, which is leading to your code running in an unexpected order.  By separating your functionality into different requests being made to the server, you can clarify this.  Have one server-side file which displays the page, and another server-side file which accepts the AJAX request.  Then have client-side code on the page which makes the AJAX request.

Comment: so there is no way to retrieve the javascript cookie in PHP as soon as it has been set considering it is a on click function?

Comment: here is one  - cookie sits on client and PHP sits on server. PHP doesn't know about a cookie until client sends it to server.  And surprisingly this is so even if all the code is packed in one file.

Comment: how do i ensure page is only reloaded once or send variable through url and retrieve it in php

Comment: @hass.: There's no way for PHP code to *read* the value when the button is clicked because the button is *on the client* and PHP runs *on the server*.  This is *exactly* what AJAX is for.  It's used when the client needs to send a value to the server when an action takes place without interrupting the page.

Comment: ok thanks, pretty sure they should be a way

Comment: @hass.: No, there shouldn't.  Under no circumstances should there ever be a way for your server-side code to arbitrarily execute on a user's web browser without the user making any request to your server.  Imagine for a moment what the internet would be like if any website could execute any code it wanted on your computer at any time, with or without your permission.  Use the tools the way they're designed.  Don't try to break the internet to fit some design that you think should be right.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and JavaScript runs on the client. They never run together, and their only connection is through a tiny pipe called HTTP. HTTP has two methods: GET and POST. First the client, by way of HTTP, requests resources from the server. Then the server, by way of HTTP, sends the resources. Back and forth through that little HTTP pipe. Since the server is the source of the resources, it's a little easier to get data from PHP to JavaScript than it is from JavaScript to PHP. You can use PHP to write JavaScript, but not the other way around. And the can't talk to each other directly

Comment: can i not use if radio button isset ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data in MySQL after calculations in JS, why don't you use AJAX requests and parse the variables to PHP script, in that case you can get response from PHP and display results on the page without refreshing the page.

Also it would be easier to do that using jQuery.

For example:

```
// JavaScipt
yessize = Math.round( 100 * ( voteyes / ( voteno + voteyes ))) + random;
nosize = Math.round( 100 * ( voteno / ( voteno + voteyes ))) + random;

$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'action.php',
    data: { ys: yessize, ns: nosize },
    success: function( response ) {
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        if( data == 'ok' ) {
            alert("Thank you for your contribution");
        } else {
            alert("There was a ploblem, please try again :(");
        }
    }
});

// PHP - action.php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['ys']) && isset($_POST['ns'])) {
        // Perform SQL query
        // You can get variables from JavaScript via $_POST['data_name']
        if($query->save()) {
            $status = 'ok';
        } else {
            $status = 'false';
        }
        echo json_encode($status);
    }
?>
```